# J8583 How set TPDU as Binary

Tags: java, iso8583, j8583

I am using j8583 Library, and I need prepend a TPDU (10 digits in binary BCD Packed) to the message.

It´s possible ?

The header of J8583 messages only use String in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had the same issue but i found a solution. Simply you need to "pack" your message and calculate the TPDU in other variable byte[]. I assume  your TDPU consist in:

```
<2 bytes length of the messages><1 byte: 60><2 bytes origin><2 bytes destiny>
```

If you have packed your message in a byte[] and your TPDU in other byte[] simply create a new byte[] and concatenate with System.arraycopy. I assume you know how to implement this.

Regards

Comment: so this TPDU thing is something that goes right at the beginning of the message, but after the length header? I guess I could add a TPDU property to `IsoMessage`... feel free to open an issue on github.com/chochos/j8583

Comment: @Chocos, Yes you can. If you are working with TCP/IP protocol don't confuse this length with the length of TCP package.